# React Navigation and redux: two dispatches?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am developing a React Native app using React Navigation and redux. I have been reading countless questions dancing around the proper way to implement the two libraries. My question is: Is there any relationship between navigation.dispatch() and redux’s dispatch()?

To be clear if I implement React Navigation with redux as described in the redux integration section could I dispatch other non-navigation actions through navigation.dispatch? This stems from trying to dispatch a logout action from a header button attached to a TabNavigator (as a child of a StackNavigator). Trying to access redux’s dispatch inside this header seems quite tricky.